# it does not display correct option details from drop down menu

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve the details of the course selected from the Course drop down module and then display a modules drop down menu listing all of the modules which belong to that course.

The problem I having though is that lets say I have these 2 options in my courses drop down menu:

```
INFO101 - Business
INFO102 - ICT
```

For some strange reason, everytime I select the top option (INFO101) from the drop down menu and click on the submit button, it always displays the other course details (INFO102) and thus shows the modules which belong to that course and not the other course.

My question is that when I submit the (INFO101) option from the drop down menu, why does it display the information of the other course?

Below is the mysqli code

```
     $sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseName FROM Course"; 

$sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

$sqlstmt->execute(); 

$sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseName);

$courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

$courseHTML = "";  
$courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
{ 
$course = $dbCourseId;
$coursename = $dbCourseName; 
$courseHTML .= '<option value="'.$course.'">' . $course . ' - ' . $coursename . '</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
} 

$courseHTML .= '</select>'; 
$courseHTML .= '</form>'; 

?>

<?php
include('noscript.php');
?>

<h1>CREATING A NEW ASSESSMENT</h1>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Course: <?php echo $courseHTML; ?><input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></th>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$submittedCourseId = (isset($_POST['courses']));

$query = "
SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
c.CourseName,
m.ModuleName
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
WHERE
(c.CourseId = ?)
ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
";

$qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$qrystmt->bind_param("s",$submittedCourseId);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$qrystmt->execute(); 

$qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

$qrystmt->store_result();

$num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

if($num ==0){
echo "<p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID '$course'</p>";
} else { 

$dataArray = array();

while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
// data array
$dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
$dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
// session data
$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseId;
$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;

}

foreach ($dataArray as $foundCourse => $courseData) {

$output = ""; 

$output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $foundCourse .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

$moduleHTML = ""; 
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

$moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleId . " - " . $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
} 
}
$moduleHTML .= '</select>';

echo $output;
```

UPDATE:

Below is what the view page source is showing:

```
        <form action="/u0000000/Mobile_app/create_session.php" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Course: <select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='INFO101'>INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology</option>
<option value='INFO102'>INFO102 - Bsc Computing</option>
</select></form><input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        <p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID 'INFO102'</p>
```

Comment: First step of debugging should be to echo out the value that's going into that query (the bind), then trace it backwards until you find the issue. Is the query doing the right thing with the wrong data, or the wrong thing with the right data? Seems probable it's the latter.

Comment: I am not sure the query is the problem, the top query is displaying all of the courses, it is this line here (I will comment in code above `$output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $course .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";` It is displaying `INFO102 - ICT` rather than `INFO101 - Business`

Comment: @MartinLyne what should I echo in order to start debugging this?

Comment: I was just looking for that value to echo, but realised it's not there, I'll expand my answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swapping:
`foreach ($dataArray as $course => $courseData)`
for
`foreach ($dataArray as $foundCourse => $courseData)`

and then all the `$course`s in the foreach should be renamed also. You use the variable `$course` at the top of your page, even if it doesn't fix the problem it will make the code more understandable.

You should also look into using PDO to abstract your database provider away http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Edit:

The code says "here are all the courses, now if you are submitting use $course and get it's details"

But at no point do you get the course that was posted, so it will (just so happen) to be using the same named variable that was "leftover" from the `foreach` at the top of the script.

I'd recommend doing as I say above then after
`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`
add
`$submittedCourseId = $_POST['coursesDrop'];`

Then add THAT to your bind
`$qrystmt->bind_param("s",$submittedCourseId);`

I think that should sort things out.

Comment: Hi, I will do this and get back to you, I can't use PDO (even tho I wish I could) because of the version of the university server

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer and edit and only problem I am getting now is that it is not able to find a course after I have submitted the drop down menu, is there anything you can see I have done incorrectly or missed out?

Comment: I'd have a little look at the source and the POST values (Press F12 in browser and look for network tab (or use Firebug), then submit the form and look for the values it actually posted, then put that echo in just before the query and make sure `$submittedCourseId` matches that value.

Comment: Actually, first, try to give the select tag a `name="coursesDrop"`

Comment: I changed the $_POST to `$_POST['courses'];` but no change. I will get on firebug and see what it's posting, and I will comment back on what its posting

Comment: It outputs this under the "Post" section in firebug `courses=&submit=Submit`, is this helpful? I don't quite seem to know where to find the value but all I know is that everytime I click on the submit buttom, it outputs this `Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID 'INFO102'` no matter which option is chosen

Comment: So that says to me that your drop down is there but the value of the option tags is empty, so check the HTML source and have a look. If so, there's the problem.

Comment: I have included an update at bottom of question of HTML page source of the drop down menu. It states the values for each drop down menu correctly but as already mentioned it is displaying the message that it can't find `INFO102` even though a. `INFO102` is legitmate and b. I didn't even chose option `INFO102`

Comment: `value='INFO101'` try `value="INFO101"` instead (double quotes)

Comment: Changed it to double quotes, still no luck, are you sure by looking at my update code that the code is definitely correct

Comment: This `$submittedCourseId = (isset($_POST['courses']));` is returning a boolean, which isn't what you need, you're looking for the value of the $_POST['courses']` not wether it was set or not

Comment: Now it has worked, I tried to put the isset so I don't get an undefined variable ut it works now. Thank you very much. If I just not included the isset and just did what you stated, this problem would have been sorted an hour ago lol

Comment: No worries, you should still take care that things cant get undefined - but getting it working right simply first is usually the best way to go. :)